# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset . Rest API + Sockets

Tags: java

I am writing a Rest API in spring boot which is making a connection to a an other Java app via Sockets. When I try to do a http request one after an other request there is absolutely no problem . But when i try to dispatch two back to back http request to my Spring boot app which in turn rights into the socket and waits for the response from the socket I get a socket exception as below,

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:182)
```

My Code Snipper is below

````
    try(Socket socket = new Socket(host, port)) {
       if (socket.isConnected()) {                    
            //An output stream instance to write in the socket to IM
            DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            //Integer denoting the start of the text message
            writer.writeByte(STX);
            writer.writeBytes(String.valueOf(message));
            //Integer denoting the end of the text message
            writer.writeByte(ETX);
            //Checksum
            writer.writeBytes(String.valueOf(new ChecksumCalculator(message,null).calculate(true)));
            log.info("Data wrote in Socket.."+message);

            //Input stream instance to read the responses from IM
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder responseMessageFromIm = new StringBuilder();

            //Exit while loop after 30 seconds and close the socket
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            int value;
            while ((value = reader.read()) != endText.get(messageSource) && (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < instrumentProperties.getSocketTimeout())) {
                //log.info(value+"->"+Character.toString((char)value));
                if(value == NAK){
                    return new IMResult(AppConstants.Res_Failed,AppConstants.Err_Nak);
                }
                if (asciiSymbols.containsKey(value)) {
                    responseMessageFromIm.append(asciiSymbols.get(value));
                }
                responseMessageFromIm.append((char) value);
                //Throw timeout exception if Instrument dit not respond back in the configured timeout
                if(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > instrumentProperties.getSocketTimeout()){
                    throw new TimeoutException();
                }
            }
            //socket.close();
            log.info("Data read from Sockets.."+responseMessageFromIm.toString());

        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

```
````

Comment: try to increase the socket time out

Comment: Increased it did not help . The first http request writes and reads from the socket and closed the socket while the second request is performing some operations in the socket..

Comment: Could you show us some more code reg. your socket-handling? Are connections dealt with in worker-threads? Is the above snippet possibly blocking further socket connections?